# Lower backlight brightness further on Lenovo Y570 running Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, brightness, backlight, laptop-display

Is there any way to lower the brightness further than the minimum brightness setting? I would like to not have my retinas burned at night.

If there is no solution to lowering the backlight, then is there some magic formula in which I can change the gamma/brightness/contrast values without totally messing up my ability to differentiate between #333333 and #000000? (i.e. not let black and dark gray look like they're both totally black)

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/191614/how-to-get-backlight-on-my-acer-extansa-5220-laptop-to-lower-than-minimum-bright